# How to get 5-7 bit from uint16_t variable?

Tags: c

In the MDR32(similar with STM32) microcontroller, there is a 16-bit STAT register that describes the ethernet status, the documentation says that 7..5 bits indicate the number of received packets, how can I get this value and save it in `uint16_t` variable?

Comment: "similar" to STM32 in that it is an ARM Cortex-M core MCU or just an MCU.  I doubt that the reference to STM32 is helpful, and it is probably inaccurate.  It is not even necessary to mention it; extraction of specific bit ranges from a word is not hardware specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you read your notation, to get bits 5, 6 and 7 from an integer you can simply do:

```
auto ethStatus = (stat >> 5) & 7;
```

Comment: Caveat - I'd strongly recommend qualifying the type (e.g. `std::uint16_t ethernet_status`).  I really, really hate "auto"...

Comment: @paulsm4 the question is tagged [C] not C++.   `auto` is incorrect in this context in any case.   In C and C++ before C++11 `auto` simply specifies a non-static local variable (which is the default in any case). Since the keyword was entirely redundant but nonetheless reserved, C++11 redefined it with entirely different semantics rather than introducing a new keyword and possibly clashing with symbols in existing code.    Since the question is tagged C, `auto` will do exactly nothing, and  `ethStatus` will have undefined type.

Comment: @Clifford: you're right - I didn't notice that.  For C++, (the new, specious redefinition of) "auto" is just "annoying" (to me, at least).  For C ... using "auto" in this manner is simply *WRONG*!

Comment: @paulsm4 : to be fair to Blindy,  looking at the edit history, it was once also tagged C++ - for about 4 minutes during which she answered.  That said being C and C++ tagged would suggest code that was semantically identical in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you shift the bits right 5 places then those 5..7 bits will be in positions 0..2. If you bitwise-and with value 0b0000000000000111U (bitmask), then all bits in positions 3..15 will be 0. This leaves you with the 3 bits that you wanted in the least significant positions:

```
unsigned ethernet_status = (STAT >> 5U) & 0b0000000000000111U;
```

You can generate the bitmask with N low bits by shifting 1 to left by N-1 and subtracting 1:

```
unsigned bit_first = 5;
unsigned bit_count = 3;
unsigned bit_mask = (1U << bit_count) - 1U;
unsigned ethernet_status = (STAT >> bit_first) & bit_mask;
```

You can store values in variables like this:

```
uint16_t variable = ethernet_status;
```

Comment: You were OK with the `uint16_t`, just not the `std::` namespace.  The OP specifically asked for `uint16_t`, so that is what you should use.  Not least because on the specified platform `unsigned` will be 32-bit.

Comment: @Clifford OP can save the value in whatever type they want. Using `std::` namespace is preferable. It is the same type as the global one, except it's guaranteed to be defined when `<cstdint>` header is included (when the alias is supported at all). It's often best to avoid lower rank unsigned types with intermediate values to avoid accidental promotion to signed.

Comment: You have missed my point;  the `std::` namespace is C++ and this question is tagged  [C].  This is an embedded system question about storage of a register value - they type the OP specified is appropriate.  You can answer the question without second-guessing or contradicting the OPs specification - that may only confuse.  Had he not specified, then of course you could decide.

Comment: @Clifford This question was tagged [c++], so I wrote a C++ answer. I'm not second guessing OP's specifications. I'm showing how they can calculate what they want. How to calculate the result doesn't hinder OP from storing the result in a type of their choice. I've added an example to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Fair point - the edit history shows the tag was removed four minutes after it was posted.  If you read a register as a `uint16_t` as you would for a 16 bit register, you might want to maintain the type throughout an expression to avoid implicit type conversions.  I am not saying you are wrong or that it matters, simply that the OP has made a design decision and specified a constraint in the solution and you had ignored it without specifying a reason.